# Matlab - Usage of uigetfile() to grab a specific type of file in a default directory

Tags: file, matlab

Does anyone know how to get a specific type of file from matlab from a default directory?

For example, I tried:

```
defaultpath='C:\'; %enter in path of interest
    [name]=uigetfile(defaultpath);
```

But how do I make it get only files with i.e. .wav extensions?

I tried:

```
defaultpath='C:\'; %enter in path of interest
[name]=uigetfile(defaultpath,
    {'*.wav', 'All Wave Files (*.wav)';...
     '*.*', 'All Files (*.*)'}, ...   
     'Pick a file');
```

but it bombs on the comma after defaultpath in the uigetfile function...

I'm sure this is something common, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Any ideas?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper usage would be:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('C:\*.wav','All Wave Files (*.wav)');
```